# Python 3 basic auth with pinnaclesports API

Tags: api, python-3.x, basic-authentication

i am trying to grab betting lines with python from pinnaclesports using their API  http://www.pinnaclesports.com/api-xml/manual

which requires basic authentication (http://www.pinnaclesports.com/api-xml/manual#authentication):

> Authentication
>
> API use HTTP Basic access authentication . Always use HTTPS to access
>   the API. You need to send HTTP Request header like this:
>
> Authorization: Basic
>
> ```
> For example:
> Authorization: Basic U03MyOT23YbzMDc6d3c3O1DQ1
> ```

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import socket
import base64

url = 'https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1//feed?sportid=12&leagueid=6164'
username = "abc"
password = "xyz"

base64 = "Basic: " + base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(username,password).encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
print (base64)

details = urllib.parse.urlencode({ 'Authorization' : base64 })
details = details.encode('UTF-8')
url = urllib.request.Request(url, details)
url.add_header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.29 Safari/525.13")    
responseData = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8', 'ignore')
print (responseData)
```

Unfortunately i get a http 500 error. Which from my point means either my authentication isn't working properly or their API is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, I don't seem to use the Python version you use, so this has not been tested using your code, but there is an extraneous colon after "Basic" in your base64 string. In my own code, adding this colon after "Basic" indeed yields a http 500 error.

**Edit: Code example using Python 2.7 and urllib2:**

```
import urllib2
import base64

def get_leagues():
    url = 'https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/leagues?sportid=33'
    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
    b64str = "Basic " + base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(username,password).encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
    headers = {'Content-length' : '0',
               'Content-type' : 'application/xml',
               'Authorization' : b64str}

    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    responseData = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    ofn = 'api_leagues.txt'
    with open(ofn, 'w') as ofile:
        ofile.write(responseData)
```